# Docker Security- user to run processes

Tags: docker, centos7

I am building the base image that will be used by all microservices in the part of the company I work for.

We run java containers and so far we were using openjdk image as is.

I am now trying to build the image from centos7 and I would like to know if someone has some recommendations regarding the way I could build my base Dockerfile such that there is a user that can be used per image.

So each application will have its own Dockerfile, that extends from the base image, and will have its own user.

Cheers
Kris

Answer (score 0):

Well if your app doesn't require 'root' then, create a new user and switch the user with USER command as follows:

```
RUN groupadd -r myapp && useradd -r -g myapp myapp
USER myapp
```

Also you might consider [dropping unused capabilities](http://rhelblog.redhat.com/2016/10/17/secure-your-containers-with-this-one-weird-trick/)